# How can I label staffs with the parts' purpose

Tags: lilypond

How can I make parts in songs in lilypond? I am typsetting a leadsheet that also shows an 'Intro' Melody, has a Verse part etc and I want to mark that up in lilypond. A bit like "Verse", "Chorus" and "PC" in this example (Doesn't necessarily have the frames around).

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [*rehearsal marks*](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation/bars.en.html#rehearsal-marks).

So just add something like this to your code:

```
\mark\markup{\bold\box "Verse 1"}
```

You'll get something like:
[image: First bar with rehearsal mark]

---

If you really want the rehearsal mark to appear below the tempo indication (like in your image above), you will have to change the priority before you add the rehearsal mark:

```
\override Score.RehearsalMark.outside-staff-priority = #0
\mark\markup{\bold\box "Verse 1"}
```

[image: First bar with rehearsal mark - below tempo]